# How do I connect to RDS in Elastic Beanstalk via Pymysql

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, pymysql

I have a python application (dash and plotly) that I'm trying to run on AWS EBS. It ran successfully when I was pulling data from different APIs within the python app (tradingEconomics and fredapi).

I have since created an RDS database so I can pull from the APIs once, store the data, and access it there. I was able to successfully connect to the database (add to, and pull from) when running it locally via pymysql. How I am doing so is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@WHAT_I_CALLED_DATABASE_INSTANCE_ON_RDS.ApPrOpRiAtEcHaRaCtErS.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/NAME_OF_DATABASE_I_CREATED_ON_MYSQLWORKBENCH')

dbConnection = engine.connect()

returned_frame = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM nameOfTableICreatedOnMySQLWorkbench", dbConnection)
```

Like I said, this works when run locally. It does not work when trying to run on EBS. (I get an internal server error 500, based on the logs it looks this is the problem.)

I think I opened up the inbound and outbound permissions on the database instance on RDS as some have suggested, but perhaps I misunderstood. This did not work.

If you have any further questions for clarification, feel free to ask.

Comment: Update: Upon further inspection, trying to import pymysql, sqlalchemy, or sklearn.preprocessing actually crashes the instance (causes 500 server error). Seems database is not the problem at all--maybe someone could comment on this?

Comment: Perhaps include more of the actual code you're using, since, without more real context, its difficult to point to an actual error. (For instance, `pd` is not defined in the code snippet you provided, but I assume that is just due to this being a contrived example.)